# JasperReports: access custom data source

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource

I am quite new to *JasperReports* and I need to create a report from a custom data source. For this I implemented the `JRDataSource` interface, with the two methods:

```
public class FacultyStudentsDS implements JRDataSource {

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField field) throws JRException {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        ...
    }
}
```

then I try to create a PDF document, this way:

```
pdf = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getAbsolutePath(),
new HashMap(), studentsDS);
```

My problem is that I do not know how to access the data I pass to the report. I have no idea what to write in the *.jrxml* file. How do I access the `studentsDS` variable that I pass to the report, in the *.jrxml* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `<detail>` band. Then within that band you can access fields from the data source by using something like the following:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{dataSourceField}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Depending on your needs, you might not need to create your own custom data source. By wrapping a `Collection` of Java beans in a [`JRBeanCollectionDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) you can access the properties of the Java beans in that collection using the above `$F{` syntax.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it is very simple.